# Unable to connect to MongoDB server using Talend

Tags: mongodb, nosql, talend

I tried connecting to MongoDB using Talend Big data solution.
Under the Metadata section, I used the "NoSql Connection" option to create a new connection, as shown below.
My MongoDb version is 4.2, there's no option for that but the 3.5.X option should work for 3.5 and above it seems.
I added the server IP in the server textbox and even tried adding a specific database name. The Username and password are correct. But still when I click the Check button to test the connection, it fails saying Athentication error -

"Connection failed!
org.talend.repository.nosql.exceptions.NoSQLServerException: Cannot connect to database!
at org.talend.repository.nosql.db.util.mongodb.MongoDBConnectionUtil.checkConnection(MongoDBConnectionUtil.java:86)
at org.talend.repository.nosql.db.provider.mongodb.MongoDBMetadataProvider.checkConnection(MongoDBMetadataProvider.java:156)
Caused by: org.talend.repository.nosql.exceptions.NoSQLServerException: org.talend.repository.nosql.exceptions.NoSQLReflectionException: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command listDatabases requires authentication'. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command listDatabases requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized"}
at org.talend.repository.nosql.db.util.mongodb.MongoDBConnectionUtil.getDatabaseNames(MongoDBConnectionUtil.java:287)
at org.talend.repository.nosql.db.util.mongodb.MongoDBConnectionUtil.checkConnection(MongoDBConnectionUtil.java:56)"

[image: MongoDbConnection]

I tried connecting to it using the JDBC connection by downloading the cdata Jar file and it shows connected successfully but I don't to use the jar file way, I want to know what I'm doing wrong with the above NoSql connection method.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some modules are missing. This was at least my problem and i have to use DB version 3.2.X even if i have a mongo db 4.2 installed.

Look in the modules window (Window -> Show View -> Talend -> Modules) if there is any not installed mongo module and install it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnWuU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the credentials did not have the right permissions. I was able to connect in the same way by using the right credentials having the appropriate permissions. Apologies for confusing you all with this question.